# can't run vbscript from cmd

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-server-2008-r2, vbscript

I got a script to ping servers which I used to execute going to the path where my file is located on CMD and type the following line

```
FileName ip logname.log
```

this is the script I run

```
hostIp      = wscript.arguments(0)
logfilename = wscript.arguments(1)
Set fso     = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Shell   = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
' OpenTextFile Method requires a Const value
' (Over)Write = 2  Append = 8   
Set logfile = fso.OpenTextFile(logfilename, 8, True)
shellstring = "%comspec% /c ping -t -f -l 32 -w 1000 " & hostIP
Set oExec   = Shell.Exec(shellstring)
wscript.echo "Ping Error log With Timestamp - Ctrl + C to halt"
Do While oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream <> True
      pingline = Date & " " & Time & " " & oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
'      If InStr(pingline, "TTL=") = 0 Then
         logfile.WriteLine(pingline)
'      End If
Loop
```

however, it doesn't work anymore whenever I execute it now it opens the file instead of executing it. any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: This looks like vbScript. This is executed with `cscript` from the command line. I.e. `cscript <filename> <ip> <log>` what is filename extension? Is it .vbs? You may have changed your file associations somehow.

Comment: nothing was changed and yes the extension is .vbs, what exactly do you mean by file associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the syntax:

```
Filename ip logname.log
```

then the action will be derived from the registry.

On my computer, I have the following.

1. Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.vbs

   - (Default) REG_SZ VBSFile
2. Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell\Open\Command

   - (Default) REG_EXPAND_SZ "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*

If you don't want to leave it to chance, you will have to explicitly include WScript or CScript in your commandline, e.g.

```
CScript Filename ip logname.log
```

The most notable difference between CScript and WScript is the behavior of `WScript.Echo`. With CScript, text is echoed to stdout and is non blocking. With WScript, text is displayed in a modal dialog box and is blocking. The former is generally preferred if (1) you're invoking the script from a Command Prompt, (2) you're invoking the script from a scheduled task.

Comment: thanks for your answer, ill try it when I get back to work. what's the difference between WScript and CScript? and im trying to add the dale to the filelog like this Set logdate = Format(Now(),"dd/mm/yy")   Set logfile = fso.OpenTextFile(logfilename & logdate , 8, True).   is that ok?

Comment: @RildoGomez no. That is not correct. That would result in `logname.log10/13/17` you've obliterated the file extension and I don't think slashes are valid in a filename.

Comment: @rildo-gomez I've updated my answer Re: difference between WScript and CScript?

Comment: It worked!! Thanks, im still working on my date thing tho :)